# Find if 2 polygons have an intersection (Geoserver)

Tags: geoserver

I need to check if 2 polygons have at least one common point. What should be a proper CQL syntax for WFS request?
And another variant if my 1st is not possible: get a list of polygons that have at least one common point or intersection with the source polygon?

Answer (score 0):

The answers to these two questions are related. I'll answer the 2nd (easier) one first. You can test for at least a point in common using the `Intersects` test so a CQL filter like:

```
intersects(POLYGON((.....)), the_geom)
```

This will return all the features that intersect the geometry stored in the `the_geom` attribute.

To limit it to a specific feature you can extend the filter to request a specific feature such as:

```
in (1) and intersects(POLYGON((.....)), the_geom)
```

to return a feature if it's `id` is 1 and it intersects.